# pg_restore using ssl certs

Tags: postgresql, ssl, pg-restore

Can somebody help me in restoring postgres db using SSL certs. I tried in below way but it didn't work

```
pg_restore "host=hostname user=username dbname=database_name sslcert=sslcert.crt sslkey=sslkey.key sslrootcert=sslroot.pem sslmode=verify-full" -f filename
```

It gives the below error

```
pg_restore: [archiver] could not open input file "host=hostname user=username dbname=database_name sslcert=sslcert.crt sslkey=sslkey.key sslrootcert=sslroot.pem sslmode=verify-full": No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The argument of `pg_restore` is not the connection string, but the file to restore. You use the `-d` option to specify the connection string:

```
pg_restore -d "host=..." filename
```

You can specify any parameters that way. A more elaborate example would be:

```
pg_restore  --format=custom -d "port=5432 host=<hostname> 
user=<username> dbname=<dbname> sslrootcert=root.crt 
sslkey=server.key sslcert=server.crt sslmode=verify-ca" ../filename.dump -v
```

Please refer to the docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgrestore.html).

Answer (score 4):

I use this in my case with digital ocean...

```
pg_restore --clean -d 'postgresql://USER:qfdvr2ata7opidy4@HOST:PORT/DATABASE?sslmode=require' --jobs 2 database.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Laurenz Albe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) answer is spot on. Here is just an expanded version of the answer to include the SSL certs.

```
pg_restore  --format=custom -d "port=5432 host=<hostname> 
user=<username> dbname=<dbname> sslrootcert=root.crt 
sslkey=server.key sslcert=server.crt sslmode=verify-ca" ../filename.dump -v
```

Please refer to the docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgrestore.html).